# Getting the last digit of number counting up

Tags: c

Say I have a number which is counting from 0 to 10000,
0,1,2,3 ... 9998, 9999, 10000

How am I able to only display the last digit on this number.
eg: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2...

I have this code but i'm not sure how to implement what I want.

```
if (count_a > 9) {
//something here
count_a = 0; //resets it back to 0
} else { //count_a is less than 9
count_a =((newtime-original_time)/100); //to get ms //this counts up in the way which I have stated above.
```

How can I loop the `((newtime-original_time)/100)` to go back to 0 once it is >9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the last (decimal) digit from a number `x`, use:

```
x % 10
```

The `%` represents the *modulo* operator, which equals the remainder after dividing by 10.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you want

```
num % 10
```

for digit `num` the result of the above operation will always range from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last digit. do count_a = num % 10

To loop back the ((newtime-original_time)/100) expression when count_a > 9 (can be re-written as when count_a == 0 since after 9, you get 0 in this case so you code should be :

```
for(num = 0; num <MAX; num++)
{
    count_a = num % 10;
    if (count_a == 0)
    {
        original_time = newtime; // this will make the expression = 0
    }
    count_a = ((newtime-original_time)/100);
}
```

Hope this helps :)